# Привет всем, никак не могу понять как это сделать

Tags: python, sqlite

мне нужно, чтобы при команде
/norma 20
в значение столбца norma в бд sqlite вводилось значение 20, либо если команда /norma 40, то вводилось 40 и так далее. никак не пойму как это можно сделать, заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: код написан на python, подключена база данных sqlite 3